# Automapper: How to get source property name from PropertyMap

Tags: automapper

How do I get the name of the source property from the property map in this code:

```
IEnumerable<PropertyMap> propertyMapList = Mapper.FindTypeMapFor<TFrom, TTo>().GetPropertyMaps();
foreach (PropertyMap propertyMap in propertyMapList)
{
    ////.....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work in AutoMapper v1 (haven't tried in v2 yet).

```
foreach (PropertyMap propertyMap in propertyMapList)
{
    var resolver = propertyMap.GetSourceValueResolvers().First();
    var getter = (IMemberGetter) resolver;
    var info = getter.MemberInfo;
}
```

This assumes that it's just a bog-standard map from one property to another, it won't work otherwise.  So, obviously, you'll want to add error checking around the cast, etc.