# AutoMapper: How do I get the name of the destination property

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-4

How do I get the name of the destination property:

```
Public class Source{
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
}

public class Destination{
    public string C_First_Name{ get; set; }
}
```

Using AutoMapper,  how do i get the name of the destination property when i pass source property Name.

Comment: how do i get the name of the destination property when i pass source property name.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: May I ask why you need that property name? And what if there are more than one destination properties? (You can map Source multiple times).

Answer (score 11):

For some map configuration:

```
var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>().ForMember(dst => dst.C_First_Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FirstName));
});
```

You can define a method like this:

```
public string GetDestinationPropertyFor<TSrc, TDst>(MapperConfiguration mapper, string sourceProperty)
{
    var map = mapper.FindTypeMapFor<TSrc, TDst>();
    var propertyMap = map.GetPropertyMaps().First(pm => pm.SourceMember == typeof(TSrc).GetProperty(sourceProperty));

    return propertyMap.DestinationProperty.Name;
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
var destinationName = GetDestinationPropertyFor<Source, Destination>(mapper, "FirstName");
```

Comment: No, I dont want mapping. When I pass FirstName, I should be able to get the C_First_Name. Its Name of the Destination property.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what are you asking. Can you add an example?

Comment: Please take a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561602/automapper-how-to-get-source-property-name-from-propertymap

Comment: my requirement is very simple : i will pass name of the source property(FirstName) and I want to get the name of the destination property(C_FIrst_Name). Let me know if you have any question.

Comment: This post is getting a little old but the question is still valid.  Here is another post that is a little more current that addresses the same issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/53371494/4505594