# AutoMapper 8.0 missing GetPropertyMaps

Tags: .net-core, automapper

Prior to AutoMapper 8.0, I used this code to find a property mapping by string, example: entity model has property named "currency_id" and DTO has property named "currency". I have defined bi-directional mapping in AutoMapper, and I used this code to find source/target property relat

```
    public static string GetDestinationPropertyFor<TSrc, TDst>(IMapper IMapper, string sourceProperty)
    {
        var mapper = AutoMapper.IMapper.ConfigurationProvider;

        // TSrc = source generic type
        // TDst = destination generic type
        var map = mapper.FindTypeMapFor<TSrc, TDst>();

        var propertyMap = map.GetPropertyMaps()
                              .FirstOrDefault(pm => 
                                    pm.SourceMember.Name == sourceProperty
                              );


        return propertyMap.DestinationProperty.Name;
    }
```

In AutoMapper Profile:

```
        this.CreateMap<EntityModels.contact, DTO.contact>()
            .ForMember(m => m.currency, src => src.MapFrom(f => f.currency_id))
        ;

        this.CreateMap<DTO.contact, EntityModels.contact>()
            .ForMember(m => m.currency_id, src => src.MapFrom(f => f.currency))
        ;
```

When I called my method like this:

```
var _dboField = GetDestinationPropertyFor<DTO.contact, EntityModels.contact>(this.mapper, "currency");

Console.WriteLine(_dboField);
// output should be "currency_id"
```

After upgrading to AutoMapper 8.0 I got this error at build:

'TypeMap' does not contain a definition for 'GetPropertyMaps' and no accessible extension method 'GetPropertyMaps' accepting a first argument of type 'TypeMap' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What are replacements for GetPropertyMaps in AutoMapper 8.0?

Thanks!

Comment: But why do you need that destination property? Maybe there is a better way to do what you want.

Comment: This is a workaround for OData bugs. API accepts arguments like property names from DTO but has to 'reflect' it to Entity model. For example: $orderby=currency should build Expression like .OrderBy(o => o.currency_id). I have this already done, what is the problem is missing feature in AutoMapper

Comment: That is done by mapping expressions. What you're doing is a hack. MemberMaps is what you want. But really, that code is not how you solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks. Could you give me a direction? What should I be looking for?

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.ExpressionMapping

Comment: Thanks! I spent a week trying to implement AutoMapper ExpressionMapping without a success. It contains some bugs, which disqualify this feature as a replacement for my current reflection & expression solution

Comment: That's most likely because of UseAsDataSource. That's old code that apparently no one wants to maintain (including yourself :)). Expression mapping means calling Map on the expression itself. You can check the tests in the repo to see how that works. And you can compare that with your own tests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Lucian suggested, MemberMaps is a possible replacement. However, PropertyMaps does exactly the same as GetPropertyMaps in AutoMapper 7.0. `DestinationProperty` has also been renamed to `DestinationMember`.

AutoMapper 7.0 code:

```
public static string GetDestinationPropertyFor<TSrc, TDst>(IMapper IMapper, string sourceProperty)
    {
        var mapper = AutoMapper.IMapper.ConfigurationProvider;

        // TSrc = source generic type
        // TDst = destination generic type
        var map = mapper.FindTypeMapFor<TSrc, TDst>();

        var propertyMap = map.GetPropertyMaps()
                              .FirstOrDefault(pm => 
                                    pm.SourceMember.Name == sourceProperty
                              );


        return propertyMap.DestinationProperty.Name;
    }
```

AutoMapper 8.0 code:

```
public static string GetDestinationPropertyFor<TSrc, TDst>(IMapper IMapper, string sourceProperty)
    {
        var mapper = AutoMapper.IMapper.ConfigurationProvider;

        // TSrc = source generic type
        // TDst = destination generic type
        var map = mapper.FindTypeMapFor<TSrc, TDst>();

        var propertyMap = map.PropertyMaps
                              .FirstOrDefault(pm => 
                                    pm.SourceMember.Name == sourceProperty
                              );


        return propertyMap.DestinationMember.Name;
    }
```

Comment: As you probably saw in the source code, member maps also includes path maps and constructor maps. So if you don't use ForPath and constructor mapping, you don't need that.

Answer (score 0):

I used this with version 12, no idea if it is correct or not.

```
public string GetDestinationPropertyFor<TSrc, TDst>(MapperConfiguration mapper, string sourceProperty)
    {
        var internalAPI = InternalApi.Internal(mapper);
        var map = internalAPI.FindTypeMapFor(typeof(TSrc), typeof(TDst));
        PropertyMap propertyMap = null;
        propertyMap = map.PropertyMaps
                          .FirstOrDefault(pm => 
                                pm.SourceMember.Name == sourceProperty
                          );

        return (propertyMap != null) ? propertyMap.DestinationMember.Name : null;
    }
```